# npm i –g tries to install to /-g folder location

Tags: npm

For some reason if I do this:

```
npm i –g karma-cli
```

I get this:

```
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /Users/me/foo/–g
```

No idea what is happening, this used to work well.

Answer (score 1):

Use --global instead. For some reason this works.

Answer (score 0):

NPM thinks you are trying to install a folder called -g. You might try using the expanded form:

```
npm install --global karma-cli
```

I would argue it is a bug in npm's command line evaluation of your invocation, but that is not for me to decide.